# Kernel Lockdown on 18.10 is blocking personally signed DKMS Modules. Can I disable it?

Tags: kernel, uefi, 18.10

I use a Firewall app called Douane that needs a DKMS module to work. App is only available as source and I use UEFI secure boot, so I've been signing my compiled modules and enrolling the keys I sign them with in my bios via mokutil (see the procedure that I've outlined in the [Douane wiki](https://gitlab.com/douaneapp/Douane/wikis/Signing-douane-dkms-module)).

Signing the modules and enrolling worked through 17.10 (kernel 4.13.x) and it even worked though 18.04 (4.15.x).

In 18.10 (uner both 4.18.x and 4.15.x), I am getting the following error in my /var/logs/kernel.log:

```
... [  278.847882] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
... [  278.848545] Lockdown: Loading of unsigned modules is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

Module is signed and DKMS is listed when I input

```
dkms status
```

but I get the impression, the Lockdown in the Kernel may not be recognizing non ubuntu key?

I tried disabling secure boot but it does not help. From reading on the internet, the lock-down mechanism is completely separate from the UEFI secure boot, so I wasn't expecting it to do anything anyway.

I want to verify this theory by disabling Kernel Lockdown. Is there a way I can do it, or add an exception for my module or is the Lockdown mechanism hard coded into the Kernel for security robustness?

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen if I logged out and closed the laptop lid, afterwards everything was frozen and I could not boot, even into recovery.  I finally found that my BIOS had changed to secure boot enabled and fast boot enabled and disks configured as RAID.  This was not what I had set my BIOS to at install.  After resetting BIOS I was able to boot normally.  I now keep my laptop lid open unless I power down.

Comment: Hi John and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I had forgotten to mention this in my question but I've already tried disabling secure boot but it does not help. From reading on the internet, the lock-down mechanism is completely separate from the UEFI secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite interesting. I'm dealing with similar problem with VirtualBox on Debian 10 (kernel 5.2.0-bpo.3 = 5.2.17). Modules are signed by self-generated key but modprobe fails to load them with error

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted
```

No track of that issue in dmesg or journal. However temorary disabing lockdown with commands

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo x > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

allows to load modules.

Comment: I have fount bug report describing exactily the same problem: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=935945